# WiFi & Hotspot doesn't want to turn on on Xiaomi Mi 10i

Tags: wi-fi, wifi-hotspot, xiaomi, mi

WiFi and hotspot stopped working after my phone automatically restart while i am playing COD. And it does not want to start. When i tried to starting the wifi it shows starting wifi but there is no effect.

I am using MI10i with MIUI14.

There is no other issue on the network.

Comment: Have you tried turning the power off an on?  If you can't get in to turn the power off, then let teh battery exhaust itself, then recharge the battery.

Comment: I tried to solve it with Factory Reset , but it did not work.  I will try your solution regarding battery.

Comment: Did the phone get hot while playing COD?

Comment: @AndrewT. Yes, It getting little bit hot.

Comment: @RohitGupta I tried with drain battery to the switch off mobile it self and then i charge it to 100% but no luck.